# How to re-enable the People application?

Tags: contacts

I am not able to add contacts on my Nexus 4. It keeps saying "Re-enable People's application to use this feature".

Comment: In settings->apps->disabled does people appear? (or do any apps appear for that matter)

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Settings > Apps >` And select the last tab named `All` . On top right corner, tap the 3 dots button, and select `Reset app preferences`. This will enable all the disabled apps on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

In settings > Apps > select top right three vertical dotts > click on Protected apps > uncehck the "People" item. Make sure this is ok with you to uncheck. You may have a reason to protect. Main is unchecked from protected apps.

Comment: One thing for sure that there is no "Protected apps" on Nexus 4, stock Android Lollipop, so you might consider to mention the Android version or whether you're using custom ROM.

Comment: CM provided protected apps option.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > Apps > and select the tab "deactivated". Then you can re-enable the app.

Comment: First,  *ollie299792458* already mentioned the same in comments so yours is adding redundancy. Second, OP didn't make sure that about the running Android version, because "Disabled" and not "deactivated" can be seen only in versions > 4.2.2, unless "deactivated" is some option introduced by a custom ROM which you might be using or have used/seen but that too is irrelevant.